# Glassfish domains start automatically without intervention?

Tags: java, glassfish

## Steps to Recreate

- `pkill -f glassfish`.
- `pkill -9 java`.
- Repeat this a couple of times for being sure.
- ps -aux| grep 'glassfish_domain_name/config'

It shows it is running from root  user. All domains are seen to be running from root user automatically

- Again kill that using `kill -9 pid` and do this for all domains.
- Automatically after some minutes it gets started from root.
- When I list domains either via root or via particular user which is intended to run it, it shows "domain not running".

The services are running almost fine but this weird issue is bugging me down. Any helps to debug this scenario?

**OK it was monit which was doing this**

Comment: That sounds like you were able to solve it ... if you did, please post the solution as an answer instead of editing it into your question. If you don't accept an answer the question will stay in the system as unsolved forever (See the [tour]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's monit script that is the culprit.